# Prevent Angular application re-routing to root on first launch

Tags: angular, angular-router

A bit of context to begin with:
My application is served with Apache (2.4) and does not have a dedicated virtualHost (as per requirements).

The following is basically my routes configuration:

```
const appRoutes = [
    { path: 'a/:id', component: AComponent }, // Use this route to set some query params
    { path: 'b/:id', component: AComponent }, // Use this route to set some query params
    { path: '', component: AComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }, // Use this route as default query params
    { path: '**', component: DefaultComponent } // Reject everything else
];
const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
    useHash: true,
});
```

During local development, all is well. But when uploading to my server and trying to launch the app with the route `a/123`, it drops the route to load the root route (`/`).
I tried enabling route tracing and I can see that it loads the correct route (`a/123`) first then re-routes to `/` and I can't figure out why.
After the first re-route to `/`, I can navigate to whatever route I want but I need it to stay on the route I opened the app with.

I welcome any input on the matter.

---

Alternatively, if the routes are a messy way to deal with that, I could maybe use the queryParams part of the URL (like `myapp/?a=123`). Would that work?

---

**Edit to add clarity:**

What happens on launch is:

```
request www.myapp.xyz/a/123
  |_ detect angular route 'a/123'
    |_ re-route to ''
      |_ Load AComponent with parameters for route ''
```

What I need it to do:

```
request www.myapp.xyz/a/123
  |_ detect angular route 'a/123'
    |_ Load AComponent with parameters for route 'a/123'
```

---

**Edit to add router trace:**

```
Router Event: t
    main.js:1 NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/a/123')
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/a/123', urlAfterRedirects: '/a/123', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'a/123', path:'a/:id') } )
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 GuardsCheckStart(id: 1, url: '/a/123', urlAfterRedirects: '/a/123', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'a/123', path:'a/:id') } )
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 ActivationStart(path: 'a/:id')
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 1, url: '/a/123', urlAfterRedirects: '/a/123', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'a/123', path:'a/:id') } , shouldActivate: true)
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 ResolveStart(id: 1, url: '/a/123', urlAfterRedirects: '/a/123', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'a/123', path:'a/:id') } )
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 ResolveEnd(id: 1, url: '/a/123', urlAfterRedirects: '/a/123', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'a/123', path:'a/:id') } )
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 ActivationEnd(path: 'a/:id')
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/a/123', urlAfterRedirects: '/a/123')
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 NavigationStart(id: 2, url: '/home')
    main.js:1 t {id: 2, url: "/home", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
main.js:1 Router Event: t
main.js:1 RoutesRec 
    main.js:1 t {id: 2, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: t}
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 GuardsCheckStart(id: 2, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
    main.js:1 t {id: 2, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: t}
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 ActivationStart(path: '')
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 2, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } , shouldActivate: true)
    main.js:1 t {id: 2, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: t, shouldActivate: true}
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 ResolveStart(id: 2, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
    main.js:1 t {id: 2, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: t}
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 ResolveEnd(id: 2, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
    main.js:1 t {id: 2, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: t}
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 ActivationEnd(path: '')
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
    main.js:1 e {snapshot: e}
main.js:1 Router Event: t
    main.js:1 NavigationEnd(id: 2, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/')
    main.js:1 t {id: 2, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/"}
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')
    main.js:1 e {routerEvent: t, position: null, anchor: null}
main.js:1 Router Event: e
    main.js:1 Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')
```

Comment: Have you tried to use redirectTo instead of component in last route?

Comment: Nope, but the problem isn't with the default (`'**'`) route, it's the root (`''`) route that gets called for no reason. Though, I agree that it would be cleaner to have the default route redirect to a specific route.

Comment: Your ' ' path should be in first order

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was the cause of the re-route.

When modifying a large project, **always** check if a 3rd-party module does not interfere!
I am using the [ngx-joyride](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-joyride) module and was using the built-in routing, which of course tried to re-route.

The correct answer is `"Silly me, check your imported modules"`